# COPY No Source files were specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Im trying to deploy a docker container to AWS CodeBuild and it keep failing on the following step:

```
COPY dist/* /var/www/html/
```

I'm sure there's something inside of that directory, and just to be sure I ran the command `ls dist`:

```
Step 4 : RUN ls dist
---> Running in cc6a985f54dd
1.1.329fd43c10e3d0fc91b9.js
3.3.d0a0148e036318c95bfe.js
4.4.d85fbfa6409009fb6e4c.js
app.a6626f87bbfc6e67618d.js
app.cd527cf8dea96798229c62fb7d983606.css
favicon.ico
humans.txt
index.html
robots.txt
vendor.d81f28030613dd8760c0.js
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM jaronoff/listmkr-prod
# Remove the default nginx index.html
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html

RUN npm run deploy:prod
# Copy the contents of the dist directory over to the nginx web root

RUN ls dist

COPY dist/* /var/www/html/
# Expose the public http port
EXPOSE 80
# Start server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Does `/var/www/html/` exist? What error message are you getting?

Comment: I’m getting the “No source files were specified” message

Answer (score 3):

The Dockerfile `COPY` command will copy files from the build "context" into your image. The build context the the folder you pass at the end of the build command. E.g. in `docker build -t myimage:latest .` command, the `.` is your context. To use the `COPY` command, the "dist/*" would need to exist in there.

Your `RUN ls dist` command is listing the directory inside the image you're building. If you want to copy files from one location inside your image to another location, you would do:

```
RUN cp -a dist/* /var/www/html/
```